# Is there a deterministic way to know that UWP view rendering/binding has completed?

Tags: uwp, screenshot, dispatcher

In WPF I could use the dispatcher to queue my next UI related code (take a snapshot of the visuals) to run after all the pending UI operations had completed:

```
...code before rendering

Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, () => 
{
...code to run after all previous UI operations have completed (snapshot of view)
});
...
```

Is there a way to do the same in UWP?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [CoreDispatcher.RunAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) API with a [CoreDispatcherPriority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcherpriority?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) of `Low` for the delegate to be called when there are no pending input events:

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, () => {
        ...
});
```

There is also the [RunIdleAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runidleasync?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Core_CoreDispatcher_RunIdleAsync_Windows_UI_Core_IdleDispatchedHandler_?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) API to schedule background tasks:

```
await Dispatcher.RunIdleAsync(new IdleDispatchedHandler(x => {
    ...
}));
```

Comment: I tried this approach previously and got the following exception was thrown: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code
WinRT information: priority
The parameter is incorrect.

priority    - I believe the microsoft docs say not to use the CoreDispatcherPriority.Idle flag.  Is there a way to dispatch this way without an exception?

Comment: @mm89: I tried the RunIdleAsync but found that it runs before rendering has completed.   In the WPF version the priorities include "ApplicationIdle", "DataBind", etc. indicating a rather granular queue priority.  With the UWP High, Low, Idle I am unsure if things like data binding and rendering are even considered.  The docs seem to indicate that the UWP Idle priority waits until the Input queue is empty, but I require the rendering queue to be empty as well.   Are you aware of any other way to achieve this?

Comment: @RandallB: No, I don't think there is any other way.